# Flip transition uinavigationcontroller push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am pushing a UIViewController in a navigation stack using the following code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:NO];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     }];
```

Now when I press back I want it to do the same animation but its not working. Any idea why?

in ViewController.m

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     }];
```

Comment: where did you put the code in ViewController.m?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually the transition should be done like this

//MainView

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

// in viewcontroller

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: could u please tell why self.view don't work instead of self.navigationController.view

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma The general idea is NavigationController holds an array of viewControllers. Internally at view level, navigationController.view will be holding viewcontroller.view and push/pop transitions is done on navigationController.view. So navigationController.view should be the transitioning view.

Answer (score 2):

```
//FirstViewController
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewcontroller
 animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

//SecondViewController
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4:

**Push:**

```
UIView.transition(with: (self.navigationController?.view)!, duration: 0.75, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
```

**Pop:**

```
  UIView.transition(with: (self.navigationController?.view)!, duration: 0.75, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
```