# Flip transition UINavigationController push does not call viewDidLoad until animation completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation

I'm animating UINavigationController push to be a flip following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982724/flip-transition-uinavigationcontroller-push), but the problem is that viewDidLoad does not get called until the animation is completed, which looks bad since I'm loading photos and such on the destination view controller. How can I ensure that the destination view controller is 'ready to go' (viewDidLoad) called and everything initialized before the animation starts?

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't believe a transition and push are meant to be nested. Transitioning is (or was) meant for providing an animation between 2 separate view controllers. The UINavigationVC maintains its "root" status while pushing others on/off its stack. I slightly suspect you found something cool about the way threading works, since UIView animations are instant under the hood. They are for animateable properties, not appear/disappear (via popping onto the stack).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your order of events is mixed up. Ideally the photos should get loaded in their own method. You can call this in the "ViewWillAppear" method so it's done before the view is loaded. In your case, if you move the image loading to a method, you can call it just above your `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];` line.

```
[viewcontroller loadImageMethod];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view 
                           duration:0.75
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                           animations:^{
                                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];
                           }
                           completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I should mention that I'm using a tableView in the destination viewController, and the photos get loaded when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for each cell. I have a feeling the root issue may be that [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO]; should not be in an animate block.